# Cannot map an F# discriminated union to an Npgsql enum

Tags: f#, npgsql

I'm attempting to map F# discriminated union to an enum that Npgsql understands. I've used this [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html) as reference.

Here's a code sample below:

```
open Npgsql
open NpgsqlTypes

type Colors =
    | Red
    | Green
    | Blue

NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<Colors>("colors") |> ignore
```

Unfortunately, I get the following compilation error:

```
A generic construct requires that the type 'Colors' have a public default constructor
```

Is there any way to add a default constructor to this discriminated union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Ngpsql, so I don't know if this is the issue, but your `Colors` union isn't an enum as you have it written. To define an enum in F#, you have to [assign an integer to each value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/enumerations), like this:

```ml
type Color =
   | Red = 0
   | Green = 1
   | Blue = 2
```

Comment: That did the trick!